# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0) Warning

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, asyncstorage

I am getting the following warning message when my AsyncStorage Item is empty **"Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0)"** So my question is: How can I handle a promise rejection?

**My code:**

```
componentDidMount() {
        try {
            // This warning only appears when 'connections' item is empty
            AsyncStorage.getItem('connections').then((token) => {
                token = JSON.parse(token);

                const getSectionData = (dataBlob, sectionId) => dataBlob[sectionId];
                const getRowData = (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[`${rowId}`];

                const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
                    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
                    sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2,
                    getSectionData,
                    getRowData,
                });

                const {dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds} = this.formatData(token);

                this.setState({
                    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds),
                });
            });
        }catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `try`/`catch` does not work on promises unless you use `await`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to catch the reject of the promise:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // This warning only appears when 'connections' item is empty
  return AsyncStorage.getItem('connections').then((token) => {
    token = JSON.parse(token);

    const getSectionData = (dataBlob, sectionId) => dataBlob[sectionId];
    const getRowData = (dataBlob, sectionId, rowId) => dataBlob[`${rowId}`];

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2,
      getSectionData,
      getRowData,
    });

    const { dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds } = this.formatData(token);

    this.setState({
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(dataBlob, sectionIds, rowIds),
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: I get a error on "=>" and when I implement it like this ".catch(console.log('empty'))" it prints out but keeps giving me the same warning message

Answer (score 0):

Axios will not allow to request data from http urls.
there are some frameworks which will make your life easy and allow your to get data from non secured http(http://something). usually those framework allows in development mode not in release mode.

Example Expo-cli, will allow to  get data from non secured http in development mode for both android and ios.
React native CLI will not allow to get data from non secured http. so there is some work around, by that u will be able to get data in react-native-cli from non secure http.

### example for ios

open - info.plist file(ios/projectname/info.plist)

add following under `NSAppTransportSecurity`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        ...
    </dict>
```